# Where does the Zohar mention each day's challenges?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, vayera, zohar

The Artscroll Stone Chumash on page 80, note 11, says the following:

באים בימים - *Coming with [their] days*.

The *Zohar* says, *"Each day in a person's life carries with it it's own challenge and mission. What is to be accomplished today cannot be postponed to tomorrow, because tomorrow has it's set of things to do."*

Does anyone know where the *Zohar* mentions this?

Comment: http://www.aish.com/tp/b/1-min-vort/274257031.html?s=mpw

Answer (score 2):

While I'm unable to find the teaching in precisely the form presented by ArtScroll, it can be deduced from what is found in the Zohar HaQadosh, [Parashat WaYera 103A](http://ateret4u.com/online/f_01776_part_4.html#%D7%93%D7%A3B%D7%A7%D7%92B%D7%A2%27%27%D7%90):

> מַאי בָּאִים בַּיָּמִים. שִׁעוּרִין דְּיוֹמִין דְּאִתְחֲזֵי כְּדֵין לְהוּ, חַד מֵאָה וְחַד תִּשְׁעִים, **עָאלוּ בְּיוֹמִין שִׁעוּרָא דְּיוֹמִין כְּדְקָא יָאוֹת**.
>
> מַה זֶּה בָּאִים בַּיָּמִים? הַשִּׁעוּרִים שֶׁל הַיָּמִים שֶׁאָז נִרְאוּ לָהֶם, הָאֶחָד מֵאָה וְהָאֶחָד תִּשְׁעִים, **נִכְנְסוּ בַיָּמִים הַשִּׁעוּר שֶׁל הַיָּמִים כָּרָאוּי**.

If "the count of their days **properly** included all the days of their lives", it can be understood that they made extraordinary use of their time.